# ActiveJob queue adapter ignored?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, backgroundworker, rails-activejob, sucker-punch

**user_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController
  def create
    MyJob.perform_later
    User.create(...)
  end
end
```

**my_job.rb**

```
class MyJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform()
    puts "START"
    sleep 3
    puts "END"
  end
end
```

**config/initializer/sucker_punch.rb**

```
require 'sucker_punch/async_syntax'
Rails.application.configure do
  config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sucker_punch
end
```

When I run `MyJob.perform_later`in a rails console, everything work fine and the logger display this message `Enqueued MyJob (Job ID: 6c857af8-a8ed-4bd0-918b-4296c4315727) to SuckerPunch(default)`

However, when I send an http request to my **user_controller**, I don't receive any response before 3 seconds (which make me think that the job is not executed asynchronously), and the logger display this `Enqueued MyJob (Job ID: e3d698eb-00d8-4849-9496-f01c53fc7217) to Inline(default)`

It seems to use the inline (default?) adapter in controllers, which is not asynchronous.

ps : I'm using `puma` as http server, and using sucker_punch without ActiveJob works fine

Comment: Have you checked your development.rb file? If there is a config option saying `config.active_job.queue_adapter = :inline` it might overwrite whatever you put in your initializer.

Comment: This line is not present

Comment: This is another stupid guess, but did you restart your rails server so the initializer could be loaded?

Comment: Yes I did it multiple times. However, putting `config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sucker_punch` in application.rb makes it work.

Comment: This must be the answer, if anyone has an idea, don't hesitate.

Comment: I had exactly the same issue with sidekiq rather than sucker_punch. Using `Rails.application.config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq` or `My::Application.config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq` both failed. The only solution was to put `config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq` directly into the application.rb file.